What do I have to do to comply with selling a game on steam if I use the libraries Openssl + Openal-soft + Libsndfile
I would prefer to statically link my game for steam, but if not I’m fine with letting it be dynamic. I just need help with the exact specifics of what I must do to accomplish for selling my software.

Have you looked into, or better still, got links to the relevant licences for those libraries?

@MadHatter here are the licensing links: https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile/blob/master/COPYING https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/LICENSE.txt https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/COPYING or https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/LICENSE-pffft

@PepeLongstrong please compile the relevant licenses / facts in the question itself by editing it and make it easy to help you by also at least giving the licenses, not just linking to the license files. Ideally you also tell us which parts of the licenses you have problems with in interpretation or where you see issues in compatibility.

@planetmaker I should have done that, sorry

So one of the licences of the libraries you link to is LGPLv2, one is LGPLv2.1, one is Apache2, and one (covering the usage of pffft inside openal-soft) is a slightly homebrew version of BSD3.  You are bound by the union of all conditions in those licences, and you desire to distribute a statically-linked version of your executable.
This means you will need to distribute your proprietary code in object-code form, so that end-users can link to modified versions of those libraries if they wish (see eg LGPLv2.1 s6a), accompany it with source code for the relevant libraries, preserve any NOTICE file that comes with the openssl source, and preserve all copyright notices.
This is just a summary, and should not be relied on as an exhaustive or authoritative list.

thanks, this answered it for me (I've also decided to dynamically link the executable since it's easier to handle/change libraries)
